# Python Slicing from Indexed Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have the following Dataframe below:

```
Rec  Channel  Value1  Value2 
Pre             10      20
Pre             35      42
Pre             42      90
Event    A      23      39
FF              50      75
Post     A      79      11
Post     B      88      69
Post            55      20
Post            62      34
Post            43      21
```

With the following code:

```
idxall = df[df['Chan'].isin({'A', 'B'})]
idx1 = idxall.iloc[[0]] #First Occurrance
idx2 = idxall.iloc[[-1]] #Last Occurrance
```

I would like to be able to take a slice of the Value1 Column for 2 instances above the first channel reading as well as 2 instances below the last instance, how would the syntax of that be if I want to read it based off the column string of Value1?

Desired Output:

```
Value 1
35
42
23
50
79
88
55
62
```

I tried using:

```
val1 = df.loc[idx1-2: idx2+2, 'Value1']
print(val1)
```

But am getting the following error: TypeError: Could not operate 3 with block values unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Can someone please advise accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

If the missing values in Channel are NaN, you can use something like

```
df.loc[(df['Channel'].shift(1).notnull()) & (df['Channel'].shift(-1).notnull()), 'Value1']

1    35
2    42
3    23
4    50
5    79
6    88
7    55
8    62
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html#pandas-dataframe-first-valid-index) and [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html#pandas-dataframe-last-valid-index) with `loc` and index slicing:

```
df.loc[df.Channel.first_valid_index()-2:df.Channel.last_valid_index()+2, 'Value1']
```

Output:

```
1    35
2    42
3    23
4    50
5    79
6    88
7    55
8    62
Name: Value1, dtype: int64
```

The problem with your approach is that you are returing a dataframe to idx and indx2, where .loc is looking for a index label.

To correct your approach you must return the index label, the add and subtract 2.

```
val1 = df.loc[idx1.index.values[0]-2: idx2.index.values[0]+2, 'Value1']
print(val1)
```